# Client resources in different machine than backend issues

Tags: java, ajax, cookies

We have a production web application that consists front end and back end web application.

For a year now we developed a new backend project in order to replace the old backend webapp.

So we tried to replace the URL called by the front end components (mainly ajax) instead of the original old backend URL to the new backend URL.

We immediately confronted a problem when trying to use a new cookie for the new backend domain (which is different). the browser wont allow us to do so.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: "the browser wont allow us to do so" : can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Cookies are intradomain only.

If this is for testing purposes, a quick and dirty way would be to edit your local `hosts` file to point `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`.

For production purposes, you'd have to actually change the domain of the new machine, to point at the old or alternatively, change domains altogether, and have [`301 Moved Permanently`](http://devdocs.io/http/rfc2616-sec10#sec10.3.2) headers redirect users to the new domain.

Another option is to direct a subdomain of `olddomain.com` to the new machine, like `new.olddomain.com`, that should also work.